# using third party CSS and JS in open source LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, third-party

could someone please provide an easiest alternate of below tags to reference js and css in LWC as the same tags cannot be used in LWC.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/bootstrap.css">

<script src="./resources/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="./resources/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Comment: There's a whole article on this topic. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library
Which part didn't work for you?  If it's not relevant for what you're doing, maybe explain why it's not relevant and what you've tried so far

Comment: thank you for your response, this article is about using third pary libs in salesforce specific LWC, not on open source LWC and I couldn't find any proper documentation which explain how can I refer JS and CSS from local file system to my lwc components